# Ionic 3 auto start permission

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, autostart

I encountered a little problem on my app. I’m developing an application that exchange push notifications client-server and I’m using the Ionic native push plugin.

The problem is that when the app is closed not receives push notification, but in background and foreground push arrives. I understood that push has this behavior because app not have auto start permissions when user installing app.

Image in attachment ( in italian, sorry )
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUsTA.jpg)

If I turn off the switch of an app in the list, this app not receive push notification when is closed. But listed apps have the switch turned off by default (Some apps are proprietary, but the other not ) . Why?

There is a way to request autostart permission to user during app installation or when user open it the first time?

I’ve searched this information for 4 days before creating this post and I’ve used the Ionic autostart plugin but not helped me.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: hello, did you solved?